# Regarding local network connection string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I need some opinions and ideas on how to choose and use sql connection string? i do search fom sqlconnectionstring's website, but i tried for few types couldn't work with my network system. can pros out there help me please?

My condition is like below:

1. I got 1 computer for hosting and i installed sql2008 express server(microsoft sql management studio), and login as window authentication. (ip: 192.168.1.101)
2. With my created database was with out any security login id and password. (.MDF)
3. I got another computers work as client to connect and access the hosting computer which hosting the sql server. there ip had set to static (192.168.1.102, 192.168.1.103, 192.168.1.104)
4. i had tested this connection string but i failed to get connect

   ```
   Data Source=192.168.1.101,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;
    Initial Catalog=myDataBase
   ```
5. I did configure the firewall to allow the 1433 ports which is my sqlserver current using port. Checked sqlserver tcp:enabled, via:enabled, Namepipe:enabled, shareMemory:enabled. Setting of allowed computer remote-able.

**So far these are what i configured, but still unable to connect, can anybody guide me?**

Comment: Data Source ="servername";Initial Catalog="dbname"; User ID="username" ;Password ="Password";

Comment: Hi zxc i do not really understand. i need to use ip to connect but not servername. And UserID="username";Password="Password" mean the sqlserver login or database login? i really abit confuse. Please guide me thanks alots!

Comment: for data Source you can use something like Data Source="10.10.10.10" and for the username password you can use the server password the credentials you set when you install the sqlserver

Comment: so i have to put Data Source="ip+port" or just "ip"?

Comment: for my experience i never use the port.. I use something like Data Source="10.11.123.10" or Data Source="(local)"

Comment: advice captured in my mind thanks very much zxc!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because you're using a windows authentication. If you're connecting to SQL server using another computer, the login of that computer should be:

1. A part of a domain where the server is (i.e. [domain]\myusername).
2. It should be added to the SQL Server's Security\Login. Go to management studio, then in the object explorer under the server, go to the folder Security\Login. You should see a list of users under login. Your user (other computer's login) should be there.

Now, if you're not part of a domain, you should use a SQL server authentication. I haven't tried using windows authentication in two computers which is not part of a domain.

Comment: so did you use SA account to login as server authentication or create your own login account for the login?

Comment: I'm usually in the development, not in production that's why I can use the SA account in my own sql server just to test the connectivity between computers. If security is not an issue, you can always use the sa account. By the way, are you in a domain environment?

Comment: not in domain just normal workgoup. ow yeah i still got 1 thing have to learn from you, i got 3 client pc, so i have to create another 3 different sqlserver user account for the 3 computer?

Comment: Well it's actually up to you, it depends on how you will set up your system. If you want to create a SQL account for each client, then you may do that. You can create an account for each, then put them in a role. You can also create one account and use it in every connection for each of your client. Are you setting up a development environment or a production environment? It will depend on your security policy.

Comment: production environment! but i think both. i had noted down what your advice thanks MAN~!